# Increase carbonation in home brewed beer?

Tags: carbonation, ale, co2, dme

I am very new to home brewing. I have finished making my first batch of DME beer. Although during bottle conditioning I could see enough CO2 bubbles getting generated, upon opening the bottles after about a week, it didn't generate the foamy head. However, if I agitate the bottle, I manage to get some foam. If I refridgerate the bottles after conditioning, the beer becomes completely flat.

Am I doing anything wrong? How can I ensure a decent foamy head and carbonation?

**Ingredients**

- Barley DME
- Magnum hops
- Ale yeast
- Priming sugar

---

- ~10 days of primary fermentation
- ~ 4-5 days of bottle conditioning

Answer (score 3):

It's only been one week?  Wait another week before trying another bottle.  It often takes 2 weeks to carbonate in my experience.  If that doesn't work, maybe you didn't use enough priming sugar.  You need about 2 tablespoons priming sugar per gallon for good carbonation.

Comment: Thanks. I have used 7 grams of priming sugar per litre. It translates to the same amount that you have mentioned. I will wait for another week for the remaining bottle and check.

Comment: Note weeks in the fridge don't count.. needs to be warm fermentation temp.